# Pyspark Mean value of each element in multiple lists

Tags: list, pyspark, aggregate, embedding

I have a df with 2 columns:

- id
- vector

This is a sample of how it looks:

```
+--------------------+----------+
|              vector|        id|
+--------------------+----------+
|[8.32,3.22,5.34,6.5]|1046091128|
|[8.52,3.34,5.31,6.3]|1046091128|
|[8.44,3.62,5.54,6.4]|1046091128|
|[8.31,3.12,5.21,6.1]|1046091128|
+--------------------+----------+
```

I want to groupBy `appid` and take the mean of each element of the vectors. So for example the first value in the aggregated list will be (8.32+8.52+8.44+8.31)/4 and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This assumes that you know the length of the array column:

```
l = 4 #size of array column
df1 = df.select("id",*[F.col("vector")[i] for i in range(l)])
out = df1.groupby("id").agg(F.array([F.mean(i) 
                            for i in df1.columns[1:]]).alias("vector"))
```

---

```
out.show(truncate=False)

+----------+----------------------------------------+
|id        |vector                                  |
+----------+----------------------------------------+
|1046091128|[8.3975, 3.325, 5.35, 6.325000000000001]|
+----------+----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Good stuff  @anky

Answer (score 1):

You can use `posexplode` function and then aggregate the column based upon average. Something like below -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import  *
from pyspark.sql.types import  *

data = [([8.32,3.22,5.34,6.5], 1046091128 ), ([8.52,3.34,5.31,6.3], 1046091128), ([8.44,3.62,5.54,6.4], 1046091128), ([8.31,3.12,5.21,6.1], 1046091128)]
schema = StructType([ StructField("vector", ArrayType(FloatType())), StructField("id", IntegerType()) ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)

df.select("id", posexplode("vector")).groupBy("id").pivot("pos").agg(avg("col")).show()
```

*Output would look somewhat like* :

```
+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|        id|                0|                 1|                2|                3|
+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|1046091128|8.397500038146973|3.3249999284744263|5.350000023841858|6.325000047683716|
+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

You can rename the columns later if required.

Could also avoid pivot  by grouping by id and pos and then later grouping by id alone to collect_list

```
df.select("id", posexplode("vector")).groupby('id','pos').agg(avg('col').alias('vector')).groupby('id').agg(collect_list('vector').alias('vector')).show(truncate=False)
```

Outcome

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id        |vector                                                                       |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1046091128|[8.397500038146973, 5.350000023841858, 3.3249999284744263, 6.325000047683716]|
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I would go your way, except I would avoid pivot. I suggest `df.select("id", posexplode("vector")).groupby('id','pos').agg(avg('col').alias('vector')).groupby('id').agg(collect_list('vector').alias('vector')).show(truncate=False)`

Comment: Good answer though